# C++ character pointer string allocated with malloc contains gibberish when printed

Tags: c++, string, memory, malloc, cout

As far as I can tell, I'm using malloc correctly to allocate a string as a character pointer.

```
  char* test = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char) * 4);

  test[0] = 't';
  test[1] = 'e';
  test[2] = 's';
  test[3] = 't';

  std::cout << test << "\n";
```

When I print the string, there are extra ascii characters at the end.

```
test²²²²ßE╜ε┬ô
```

My hunch is that the characters in "test" are taking up less than the max memory I'm allocating.
The extra text I'm seeing might be excess memory that hasn't been written with anything meaningful.  I won't necessarily know the exact length at allocation time, though, since that string will be assembled dynamically.

My question is how to refactor this to trim that fat off.  If I know the character length of the string, can I truncate the final product somehow?  Is there a better way to allocate that space that I'm unaware of?  Is there a way to limit the number of characters that are printed?

Comment: *My hunch is that the characters in "test" are taking up less than the max memory I'm allocating.* -- Your string is not null-terminated, and it has nothing to do with `malloc`.  For example, `char test[4] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};` suffers from the same issue.  `std::cout << test` is looking for the terminating null, and you didn't provide it in the string.

Comment: Another reason you should avoid C-Style strings and use `std::string`.  See also `std::string::c_string()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're not allocating enough memory to hold a complete C-style string (which requires one additional `char` to hold the `NUL` terminator)
2. You're not providing the `NUL` terminator, nor using a zero-ing allocator, so the string won't be `NUL` terminated even if you allocate enough memory.

`malloc` doesn't return pre-zeroed memory, so if you are creating a C-style string in the memory returned, you must manually `NUL`-terminate it, or C-string APIs will just keep reading until they encounter a `NUL` by coincidence or crash. What you're seeing is not *excess* memory (though `malloc` often overallocates a bit to round off allocation sizes, there's no guarantee it's happening in any particular case), but *adjacent* memory in the heap.

For your code, just allocate the extra `char` for the `NUL` (you always need one more `char` than what you expect to put in the string) and add it explicitly and you're fine:

```
  char* test = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char) * 5);  // Allocate one extra character for the NUL

  test[0] = 't';
  test[1] = 'e';
  test[2] = 's';
  test[3] = 't';
  test[4] = '\0';  // NUL terminate

  std::cout << test << "\n";
```

Alternatively, use `calloc` to ensure the whole buffer is zeroed up-front, so anything you don't set is safely zero-ed:

```
  char* test = (char*)calloc(5, sizeof(char));  // Allocate one extra character for the NUL with zero-ing calloc

  test[0] = 't';
  test[1] = 'e';
  test[2] = 's';
  test[3] = 't';
  // No need to add NUL, test[4] guaranteed to be NUL already

  std::cout << test << "\n";
```

Of course, in idiomatic C++, you'd almost never use `malloc`, nor would you use C-style strings unless forced to do so (`std::string` exists, use it!), so idiomatic C++ would look like the much simpler:

```
#include <string>

using std::literals;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto test = "test"s;
    // Or if you don't like using literals:
    // std::string test("test");
    // Or if you want to guarantee no allocation on C++17 and higher,
    // with a #include <string_view> and the std::literals usage:
    // auto test = "test"sv;

    std::cout << test << "\n";
}
```

any of which avoid the need to manually match allocation size to string size, making it much harder to shoot yourself in the foot like you just did.